# gridview custom paging and sorting no objectdatasource

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm following the example provided here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb497936.aspx

The top half shows a stored procedure which can be used to return just the records needed, so for example if I have 100 records and want to display just 10 per page I can use the proc to tell it the maximum number of rows I want and the pageIndex to begin on. Is there a way to do the same thing without ObjectDataSource, so use a custom DataAccess layer? I'm able to get back the 10 records I want, but I don't get paging then as the GridView see only 10 coming back from the proc, is there a way to tell it I have 100, but am only displaying these 10?

Answer (score 0):

As far as your DAL is concerned if the stored procedure returns 10 records, then that's all your DAL will know. Your DAL will have no way of knowing how many records are in the underlying data unless you tell it.

If you want the stored procedure to return say 10 of 100 rows and you want the DAL to know there was 100 rows in total, then you need to pass out that value separately - in an output variable perhaps?

If you are doing paging in your stored procedure, you may lose the performance you were trying to gain if you also evaluate the total number of rows affected.

It sounds as if you solution could be architected better, but we would need to better understand your requirements and what you are trying to achieve before providing specific architectural advice.